# Is php http request synchronous?

Tags: php

Is php http request synchronous?

I know two main ways to send http requests to php. php or library.

I saw in one article that all code in php works synchronously.

so, I wonder if http requests also work synchronously.

Is it correct? Was what I saw wrong?

Comment: _php http request_ This is a pretty confusing title!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Thank you for your question. However it seems like you are not familiar with the guide of Stack Overflow to [How To: Ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Please read it and adjust your question accordingly by using the [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77068047/edit) option. Happy coding!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, PHP HTTP requests are synchronous by default.

When you send an HTTP request using functions like file_get_contents, curl_exec, or when using PHP's built-in fopen to open a remote URL, the PHP script typically blocks and waits for the response from the remote server before continuing with the script's execution. This means that the script will pause and wait for the response to arrive before it can proceed to the next line of code.

Here's an example using file_get_contents to make a synchronous HTTP request:

```
$url = 'https://somewebsite.com/api/';
$response = file_get_contents($url);
echo $response; // This line will execute after the response is received.
```

If the remote server takes a long time to respond or doesn't respond at all, it can lead to delayed script execution.

Comment: To complete the answer: you can do multiple curl requests in parallel with multi_curl. Also libraries like amq or the Swoole extension.